# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

My problem is that my program builds with no errors and then whenever I click a button it throws the error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" on the line of code:
`SubButton1Outlet.isEnabled = true`

I am trying to make a button set to disabled in the storyboard editor enable itself. I made sure the IBOutlet was connected to the right button in the storyboard but it's still throwing the error.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CallMemory()
        SubButton1Outlet.isEnabled = true
    }
    
    @IBAction func SubButton1(_ sender: Any) {
        SubNumber = 1;
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var SubButton1Outlet: UIButton!
```

Here is the whole section of code related to the problem and some screenshots of Xcode. Full GitHub Project: https://github.com/DarkCat736/SubscriptionManager/

[Xcode Simulator Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N0IF.png)

[Xcode Code Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mam3j.png)

[Full Xcode Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CcTg.jpg)

What I Expected:

- Program loads
- SubButton1 becomes enabled
- `var SubNumber` is set to value `1`
- SubButton1 is clicked and another scene opens

What Happened:

- Program loads
- SubButton1 becomes enabled
- SubButton1 is clicked
- Program throws error and halts

Comment: Try removing and then recreating the connection to the  button

Comment: Read up on Swift variable naming conventions, and learn to follow them. Variables and constants should start with lower case letters. Types should start with upper case. (So `SubButton` and `SubButton1Outlet` should be `subButton` and `subButton1Outlet`, respectively.) But I would not name an action <somethingButton>. It's not a button, it is a block of code (an action) that runs when a button is tapped. The outlet is the reference to the button. That's what you should call `subButton1`.

Comment: BTW, "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" is probably **the** most common error that new Swift developers deal with. Learn to understand Optionals and how to deal with them safely. It's a subject worth studying intensely until it becomes second nature. (it will haunt you until you master it.)

Comment: How are you creating an instance of `ViewController`? Through code or via the storyboard?

Comment: You might want to upload your project to Github and post a link to it. There are various beginner mistakes you could be making in your app's setup that are hard to diagnose from a few screenshots.

Comment: Full GitHub Project: https://github.com/DarkCat736/SubscriptionManager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface Builder sets up IBOutlets as "implicitly unwrapped optionals", which means if the outlet link is broken, your code will crash.

Your `SubButton1Outlet` is such an implicitly unwrapped optional. (Note the exclamation point after the type.

For some reason that outlet is nil. Check the link in Interface Builder.

If it shows as connected, you may be creating your view controller in a way where you're not loading the views from the storyboard at all. You'll have to show us how you are instantiating and loading your view controller before we could help diagnose that however.

### Edit:

I've looked at your project.

Your storyboard is a mess.

It contains 6 different view controller scenes, each of which is an instance of your same class "ViewController."

Don't do that. Define a different custom subclass of UIViewController for each view controller in your storyboard. Each one should have outlets and actions for the buttons and views that that view controller manages.

Your root view controller has a button titled "SubButton1" that has a modal segue to your `SuscriptionView` Scene, which contains a view controller that is also of the same class `ViewController`. However, the `SuscriptionView` scene does not include a button `SubButton1Outlet`, so in that instance of your `ViewController`, the IBOutlet is nil. Thus, when `viewDidLoad` fires, it tries to execute the line

```
SubButton1Outlet.isEnabled = true
```

However, `SubButton1Outlet1` in that instance of your ViewController is nil, so your app crashes.

Again, your SuscriptionView scene should contain its own custom subclass of UIViewController. Let's call it `SubscriptionViewController`. When you invoke the modal segue from your root view controller to your `SuscriptionView` scene, it will invoke a different kind of view controller, a `SubscriptionViewController`. That view controller's viewDidLoad will have code unique to that view controller, and that `viewDidLoad` method won't try to set a `SubButton1Outlet1` that doesn't exist in the `SubscriptionViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know how I'm loading the views, but all the other IBOutlets are working and I've made sure the builder connection is correct. This is the problem, I've tried these solutions and it keeps returning nil for some reason. Anything else it could be?

Comment: Also, when I used the correct name formatting it started throwing an NSException error in the AppDelegate at line `@main`

Comment: So edit your question to show the Interface Builder "connections inspector" for your view controller. Also explain how you invoke the view controller that's crashing, and what the button that crashes does. Does it have a segue link? The crash you show in your screenshot is occurring in `viewDidLoad`, which gets called when a view controller's view is first loaded, not on a button click.

Comment: I did not down-vote your answer. I am a beginner, so I do not know exactly what you are asking for, but the view controller is launched by the loading screen, the button launches another view controller scene by presenting it modally in full screen, and I know the crash is in viewDidLoad(). I did that as a test for the rest of my code. It should enable the button on launch. Here is my project on GitHub: https://github.com/DarkCat736/SubscriptionManager/

Comment: See the edit to my answer. You are misunderstanding how to use storyboards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this error completely confused me. I will fix my storyboard and add the extra view controllers.